# Comparing 2 null datetimes not returning equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, triggers

In an update trigger I am comparing 2 nullable datetimes, that both happen to be null in my current test and it is returning that they are not equal.

```
@ExpirationDateChanged = case when i.ExpirationDate = d.ExpirationDate then 0 else 1 end
```

In this case i.ExpirationDate and d.Expiration date are null but instead of getting the expected 0, I am getting 1.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is not equal to `NULL` using equality comparison.

Comparing NULL values for equality is `UNKNOWN` under ANSI setting (the default)

You need to add an extra condition to explicitly test both columns for `NULL` using `IS NULL`:

```
@ExpirationDateChanged = case 
                             when (i.ExpirationDate IS NULL AND d.ExpirationDate IS NULL) OR
                                   i.ExpirationDate = d.ExpirationDate then 0 
                             else 1 
                         end
```

Comment: To add to that, NULL is never equal to anything.  A comparison of a NULL value will never return true.

Comment: I wasn't correcting you, just adding a more explicit explanation. Good answer.